# Listen to the 'reloading' event of watch (e.g. to close db connection) in mocha test

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

I have got this error:

> Could not connect to MongoDB!
>
> Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.
>
> OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Article` model once compiled.

when I use the `--watch` to run my mocha test. It is because the test runner is trying to reload the application (server.js) and it is trying to recompile models.

I find several related questions on SO but they do not specifically apply to the `--watch` scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that by modifying statement:

```
var People = mongoose.model('people', mongose.Schema({...});
```

to read

```
var People = global.People = global.People || mongoose.model('people', mongose.Schema({...});
```